# How to get mongodb record and apply filter on nested json field?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I have a mongo database and I use it with eloquent orm through this package `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb`. I want to get a record and apply a filter on a specific attribute that is of `json` type.

Example of data:

```
# testCollection
{
    _id: ObjectId('630de2aa0ec78d9dfd0d23a2')
    label: 'testLabel',
    jsonField: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId('630de2aa0ec78d9d77777777'),
            disabled: true
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('630de2aa0ec78d9d88888888'),
            disabled: false
        },
        {
            _id: ObjectId('630de2aa0ec78d9d99999999'),
            disabled: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Consider the example above, I try to get record `630de2aa0ec78d9dfd0d23a2` with `jsonField` filtered on `disabled` at true.

This is what i actually do to with laravel:

```
return \array_column(\array_filter(
    TestCollection::find('630de2aa0ec78d9dfd0d23a2')->jsonField,
    static fn(array $jsf): bool => true === $jsf['disabled']
), '_id');

// output
// ['630de2aa0ec78d9d99999999', '630de2aa0ec78d9d77777777']
```

What is the way to do that only with eloquent query (without php functions `array_filter` and `array_column` ?

Comment: You show `jsonField` as being an object.  Isn't it actually an array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `jsonField` is an array, here's one way to use `find` with a projection that only returns the `_id`s you want.

```js
db.collection.find({
  _id: ObjectId("630de2aa0ec78d9dfd0d23a2")
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "jsonFieldIds": {
    "$map": {
      "input": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$jsonField",
          "cond": "$$this.disabled"
        }
      },
      "as": "trueRecs",
      "in": "$$trueRecs._id"
    }
  }
})
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "jsonFieldIds": [
      ObjectId("630de2aa0ec78d9d77777777"),
      ObjectId("630de2aa0ec78d9d99999999")
    ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0E8GIAuIUQ5).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but i need to realize this with Eloquent ORM and Laravel, not the way in pure mongodb query.

Comment: @Lounis  I don't know Laravel/Eloquent.  I had heard there was some sort of "raw" mode that allowed easy use of MongoDB queries, but I really don't know.  I thought your intention was to move some of the work to the MongoDB server, and that's what this query/projection does.  Hopefully there's an easy MongoDB -> Laravel/Eloquent translation.

Comment: Of course we could do that with raw query but this way we are not getting Entity object from eloquent ORM (instead it's an `BSONDocument` object), so this is the reason why i expect to make this query with eloquent native query.

Comment: @Lounis  OK, good luck!